# How to keep separate folder for desktop and mobile?

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to keep 2 separate template folder(s) for `desktop` and `mobile`. But I am not able to figrueout the correct way.

Any one help me for this?

If I am wrong, please correct me.

here is my requirement what I looking for :

[image]

[Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/49057029c88ae4f2eab50ff64560ce29?openFiles=templates.mobile.my-route.hbs%2C)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better way to achive this.

But to solve your need, you can use the [`templateName` property](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/2.14/classes/Ember.Route/properties/templateName?anchor=templateName) of the route.

[Here](https://ember-twiddle.com/a6cc9dfc7193dcff405da033e28d96c7?openFiles=routes.my-route.js%2C&route=%2Fmy-route) is the updated twiddle.

Comment: Is that mean each and every router has to set the template path? there is no global configuration? my project size is very large. this is not such easy to maintain the code.

Comment: You can handle it by reopening Ember.Route.
But again there need to be a better way. Eg. building two different applications for different platforms. Handling common parts in a common addon.

Comment: `isDesktop()` - is inbuild method? if not is there any inbuild or recommended ember approach?

Comment: Nope its my mock implementation in the 3th line of that route. To implement it have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser). Also [ember-responsive](https://github.com/freshbooks/ember-responsive) addon can help you.

Comment: I tried here : `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45892997/how-to-inject-responsive-object-to-application` not working. can you help me to setup please?

Comment: In my application router how can i get the value here is my try : `https://ember-twiddle.com/1b8b48e0dbeab6f0d870b49a548923ad?openFiles=initializers.application.js%2C`

Comment: Put `media:Ember.inject.service(),` line to your route. Remove initializer.